# How to use xdmp:estimate() in searchable XPath expression?

Tags: xpath, xquery, marklogic

It is always advisable to use `xdmp:estimate` instead of `fn:count`. I know how to use it in cts:search but not sure on searchable XPath expressions. For example, I am trying to return the count of `search:facets` returned after performing `search:search`, like this -
`xdmp:estimate($search-result/search:facet/search:facet-value)`but I get error
`XDMP-UNSEARCHABLE-- Expression is unsearchable` while using `fn:count` works just fine.
Help!

Answer (score 5):

`xdmp:estimate()` returns the number of fragments that match. Your example is doing filtering via the xPath expression.

What you seem to be looking for is likely a valid use of `fn:count()`

It us "usually" advisable to use `xdmp:estimate()` when your use-case allows.

A link to the `xdmp:estmate` vs `fn:count` part of the search developers guide:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/count_estimate

Comment: you mean xdmp:estimate() is useful when we want to count no. of fragments?

Comment: That is specifically what xdmp:estimate does - return the number of fragments. So, when it is best to use and when fn:count is best to use depends on what you are doing, how your data is structured and how your content is fragmented (if you have fragment roots/parents, etc). I just updated the post with the appropriate reference information in the search developer's guide.